# VBscript ,writing into registry

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I am having trouble modifying Registry key values,

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\MyNewKey\MyValue", "0"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA","0"
```

when i execute the code it always gave an error, 'Invalid Root in Registry'
whats wrong with the code could somebody explain this ?

Comment: Access to HKLM is restricted to administrators, tried running it as such?

Comment: I am running that code as an administrator already

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72z3kxt%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" instead of HKLM.  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" instead of HKCU...

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//yfdfhz1b%28v%3dvs.85%29) *"You may use abbreviated versions of root key names with the `RegWrite` method. The five root keys are listed in the following table."* `HKLM` is one of those abbreviations, this answer is nonsense.

Comment: Doesn't work:
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA","0"

It states --------------------------- Line: 2 Char: 1 Error: Invalid root in registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA". Code: 80070005 Source: WshShell.RegWrite

Answer (score 0):

There are three arguments regarding registery write in vbs . For more information please head towards
https://www.vbsedit.com/html/678e6992-ddc4-4333-a78c-6415c9ebcc77.asp

Problem is that you are not referring the size of registery i.e REG_SZ, DWORD , QWORD etc.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\NewRegisteryWrite", "MyString", "REG_SZ"
```